# How do i transcode video files with ffmpeg by piping the in and output over ssh or by sftp

Tags: ssh, ffmpeg, sftp, sshfs

I have a server with the video files i want to transcode to x265 and have ssh/sftp acces to it. 
But i am not root on my transcoding machine, therefore couldn't install `sshfs`, so i decided to pipe the files over ssh (i know the performance issues).

The input works with the command

```
ssh -p 1022 USER@SERVER cat input.mkv | ffmpeg -i - -c:v libx265 -preset slow -x265-params crf=21 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

But i failed to save the output file again back on the server over ssh following this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/839955/piping-output-from-ffmpeg-avconv-over-ssh-to-a-file

```
ssh -p 1022 USER@SERVER "ssh -p 1022 USER@SERVER cat input.mkv | ffmpeg -i - -c:v libx265 -preset slow -x265-params crf=21 -c:a copy -f matroska pipe:1" | cat > output.mkv
```

So how do i combine those two piping commands correctly? 
Or can you think of more intelligent ways to access those files?

Answer (score 0):

For saving an output via ssh, you should write something like this :

```
mycommand --sentoStdout | ssh user@host 'cat > /to/dest/file.type'
```

So, in your case, you should write this :

```
ssh -p 1022 USER@SERVER cat input.mkv | fmpeg -i - -c:v libx265 -preset slow -x265-params crf=21 -c:a copy pipe:1 | ssh -p 1022 USER@SERVER 'cat > output.mkv'
```

Comment: @cmake.fr Thanks, i tried. But it keeps me asking, if i want to trust the fingerprint of my server. And no matter how often i type in 'yes', it keeps asking. Could it be, that the two ssh connections interfere?